# Xcode - Swift 4 Encoding error

Tags: xcode, encoding, swift4

I have this code :

```
    let data = "NgAzADYANQA1ADEANwA0ADgANQA1ADQANgA4ADgAMAA0ADcALwAvAGIAYQAwAGQAZABlAGQANAAtAGYANAAzAGUALQA0ADAANABkAC0AYQAzAGYAYgAtADQAZQA2ADIAZQBhADkAMgBiADMAYgBiAA=="
    let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: data, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let decodedString = String(decoding: dataDecoded, as: UTF8.self)
    print(decodedString)
```

On my output window, i have this result :

> 636551748554688047//ba0dded4-f43e-404d-a3fb-4e62ea92b3bb

But on my variable, i have :

> 6\03\06\05\05\01\07\04\08\05\05\04\06\08\08\00\04\07\0/\0/\0b\0a\00\0d\0d\0e\0d\04\0-\0f\04\03\0e\0-\04\00\04\0d\0-\0a\03\0f\0b\0-\04\0e\06\02\0e\0a\09\02\0b\03\0b\0b\0

please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your input data is not int UTF-8, try this:

```
let decodedString = String(data: dataDecoded, encoding: .utf16LittleEndian)
```